# VueJS app works in localhost but breaks in development environment (not even production)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

My VueJS app (with Vuex) works in local environment with no problem. However, when I deploy it to development env. (`process.env.NODE_ENV` equals to 'development') it breaks in one of the modules of Vuex store. (after this I didn't deploy it to prod of course)

It says serviceB that I imported in modeuleX of Vuex store is `undefined`. Here is my project structure:

```
src
├── App.vue
├── components
.
.
.
├── services
│   ├── index.js   // file that exports services
│   ├── serviceA.js
│   ├── serviceB.js
│   └── serviceC.js
├── store
│   ├── index.js   // file that exports Vuex store
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── moduleX.js
│   │   ├── moduleY.js
│   │   └── moduleZ.js
.
.
.
```

store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import createLogger from 'vuex/dist/logger';

import moduleX from './modules/moduleX';
import moduleY from './modules/moduleY';
import moduleZ from './modules/moduleZ';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    moduleX,
    moduleY,
    moduleZ,
  },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? [createLogger()] : [],
});
```

services/index.js:

```
import serviceA from './serviceA';
import serviceB from './serviceB';
import serviceC from './serviceC';

export { serviceA, serviceB, serviceC };
```

services/serviceC.js (the service that imports `store`)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { event } from 'vue-analytics';
import store from '@/store';

export default {
  sendEvent(evt) {
    console.log(store.getters['moduleX/something']);
    event(evt);
  }
};
```

services/serviceB.js:

```
export default {
  someMethodB() {
    return localStorage.getItem('bProp');
  },
};
```

an here is how I use it in store/modules/moduleX.js:

```
import { serviceA, serviceB, serviceC } from '@/services';

const defaults = {
  aProp: serviceA.someMethodA(), // works
  bProp: serviceB.someMethodB(), // NOT WORKING
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: { ...defaults },
  getters: {
    something: true,
  },
  mutations: {
    // use serviceC here with no problem
  },
};
```

serviceA and serviceC works fine but `serviceB` is `undefined`. And because of that the app fails building.

Again, it works fine in localhost. Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value from your function.

```js
export default {
  someMethodB() {
    return localStorage.getItem('bProp'); // *** RETURN HERE ***
  },
};
```

Comment: no... it's not about it. serviceB's itself is `undefined`. (also, there is a `return` actually. I forgot to write it here, correcting now.)

Comment: do you have a read only file that is not getting updated on your server?  rename file serviceB to serviceB2 and try again.